# File Upload Progress Bar without using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, file-upload

I have a standard multi-part form that uploads a file to a remote URL, which responds with redirect header.

Because the page loads from www.site-a.com & the form posts to www.site-b.com, I can't use the usual ajax.form submission process.

I have no access to configure the remote www.site-b.com server.

Is there a way to monitor the current upload progress directly from the browser with jQuery?

Comment: Nope. You could try using http://socket.io/, but AJAX would be simpler.

Comment: `progress` is not backward compatible. PHP can now test for progress. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php .

Comment: Thanks for the comments: unfortunately both solutions require access tot he remote server, which I don't have :(

Answer (score 0):

If the www.site-b.com site is yours, you can set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to * or site-a and then use ajax.

Comment: Hi, thx for the response. www.site-b.com is a 3rd party service that I have no control over, and they are unhappy to modify in any way.